# C++, cannot open source file "ifstream" Visual Studio

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am getting two syntax? errors even though the project builds successfully. Certain parts of my code are highlighted as red in Visual Studio in the following locations that I have commented at:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ifstream> //include is highlighted// Error: cannot open source file "ifstream"

using namespace std;

class DictionarySorter{
public:

    DictionarySorter(){

    }
    void readDic(string name){
        ifstream dicFile (name); //dicFile is highlighted here// Error: incomplete type is not allowed

    }
private:
    vector<string> v;


};
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) is defined in the header `<fstream>`. There is no standard header `<ifstream>`.

Comment: I was referencing a Youtube tutorial, which used ifstream header.... You are right.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ `ifstream` takes a `c-string` as the parameter for the opening of a file name. Simply change the `name` in `ifstream dicFile(name);` to `ifstream dicFile(name.c_str());`

You're also including a library called `ifstream` which doesn't exist. The `ifstream` object is within the `fstream` library.

Comment: There is also an overload that takes in an `const std::string&` so the first part of your answer is invalid.

Comment: @clcto hmm, that must be a c++11 thing. I've been using 98 for school for a few years and always needed to use `.c_str()` for a normal `string` value.

Comment: Fair enough, the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) do say since c++11 on that constructor.